# Basic Integration Problem Using e

Tags: calculus

How would I integrate the following problem? :

> Evaluate the given integral using the substitution (or method) indicated
>   $$\int (x + \color{red} 3) e^{(x + \color{red} 3)^2} dx; \quad u = (x + \color{red} 3)^2$$

So far I have: DU: (2x+6)DX

```
           DX: DU/(2x+6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave $du$ factored as

$$du = 2(x + 3) dx$$

and group the integral as

$$\frac 1 2 \int e^{(x + 3)^2} \Big(2(x + 3) dx\Big)$$

Now making the substitution, we're left with

$$\frac 1 2 \int e^u du$$

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Yes but how did you get the (1/2) on the outside of the integral?

Comment: Notice that I also multiplied by $2$ on the inside; essentially, I wrote $1 = \frac 2 2$ and moved the $1/2$ outside.

Answer (score 1):

Using your method of letting $u=(x+3)^2$, we have $du=2(x+3)dx.$  This is equivalent to $dx=\frac{du}{2(x+3)}$.  Now, the integral is
$$\int(x+3)e^u\frac{du}{2(x+3)}.$$Notice the $(x+3)$'s cancel out and the $\frac12$ can be pulled out because its constant. Then you are left with
$$\frac12\int e^u\ du$$
Now, just integrate then substitute back for $x$.